# Different results LINQ vs 'normal' C# code

Tags: c#, linq

I am scratching my head on this.  The code below I would think should produce the same results.  However, they don't.  I am clearly missing something.  The LINQ query returns a long that is smaller than the plain C# code does.

```
    public static long GetListSize(SPList list)
    {
        long longInt = 0;
        long byteSize = (from item in list.Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
                         where item.ParentList.EnableVersioning == false
                         select long.TryParse(item["File_x0020_Size"].ToString(), out longInt) ? longInt : 0)
                 .Concat(from iItem in list.Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
                         where iItem.ParentList.EnableVersioning == true && iItem.Versions.Count > 1
                         from vItem in iItem.Versions.OfType<SPListItemVersion>()
                         select long.TryParse(vItem["File_x0020_Size"].ToString(), out longInt) ? longInt : 0)
                 .Sum();

        return byteSize;
    }

    public static long GetListSize2(SPList list)
    {
        long byteSize = 0;
        long fileSize = 0;
        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            if (item.ParentList.EnableVersioning == true && item.Versions.Count > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < item.Versions.Count; i++)
                {
                    long.TryParse(item.Versions[i]["File_x0020_Size"].ToString(), out fileSize);
                    byteSize += fileSize;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                long.TryParse(item["File_x0020_Size"].ToString(), out fileSize);
                byteSize += fileSize;
            }
        }
        return byteSize;
    }
```

When I run them against the same list:

GetListSizeForCurrentItems: 2401408086
GetListSizeForCurrentItems2: 2401408086
GetListSizeForItemVersions: 459902667
GetListSizeForItemVersions2: 459902667
GetListSize: 459902667
GetListSize2: 2842896668

Refactored code to isolate each query in the above:

```
    public static long GetListSizeForItemVersions(SPList list)
    {
        long longInt = 0;
        long byteSize = (from iItem in list.Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
                         where iItem.ParentList.EnableVersioning == true && iItem.Versions.Count > 1
                         from vItem in iItem.Versions.OfType<SPListItemVersion>()
                         select long.TryParse(vItem["File_x0020_Size"].ToString(), out longInt) ? longInt : 0)
                 .Sum();

        return byteSize;
    }
    public static long GetListSizeForItemVersions2(SPList list)
    {
        long byteSize = 0;
        long fileSize = 0;
        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            if (item.ParentList.EnableVersioning == true && item.Versions.Count > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < item.Versions.Count; i++)
                {
                    long.TryParse(item.Versions[i]["File_x0020_Size"].ToString(), out fileSize);
                    byteSize += fileSize;
                }
            }
        }
        return byteSize;
    }

    public static long GetListSizeForCurrentItems(SPList list)
    {
        long longInt = 0;
        long byteSize = (from item in list.Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
                         where item.ParentList.EnableVersioning == false
                         select long.TryParse(item["File_x0020_Size"].ToString(), out longInt) ? longInt : 0)
                         .Sum();
        return byteSize;
    }
    public static long GetListSizeForCurrentItems2(SPList list)
    {
        long byteSize = 0;
        long fileSize = 0;
        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            long.TryParse(item["File_x0020_Size"].ToString(), out fileSize);
            byteSize += fileSize;
        }
        return byteSize;

    }
```

The change to Concat() definitely changes results.

An extra set of eyes would be beneficial.  What am I missing in translating the plain C# into LINQ.

Comment: Aside from using Union instead of Concat, you're including the EnableVersioning==false values in the first part of the query, whereas in your normal C# code you're using an "else" to only let a single item contribute to *one* part of the sum.

Comment: Hi Jon, you are right about the else (and the Union/Concat).  However, if I add a where clause to the first part of the query with EnableVersioning == false, I am getting a rather large difference in the results. I am going to update the question to reflect what is happening now.

Comment: Note that it would be easier for us to help you if you could provide a short but *complete* example, and remove anything extraneous (like the string parsing - are you sure that's even required?)

Comment: Is it possible that for an item ParentList.EnableVersioning can be true with the number of versions being 1? If yes then GetListSize2 does the wrong thing. The else part in GetListSize2 is executed if `item.ParentList.EnableVersioning == false || item.Versions.Count <= 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is in the [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341731%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It returns... (emphasis mine)

> An `IEnumerable<T>` that contains the elements from both input sequences, **excluding duplicates**.

So if you have duplicates in your list, you are only counting unique values. Use `Concat` instead.

Comment: Hi, this does provide the answer the the bulk of why the numbers are off.  I am still having an issue with the totals not matching. I am going to update the question to reflect how things are now.

Comment: He always does :) . You can only accept answers, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

In GetListSize2() you don't check if long.TryParse has return false.

The TryParse method is like the Parse method, except the TryParse method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails.It eliminates the need to use exception handling to test for a FormatException in the event that s is invalid and cannot be successfully parsed.

So, if there are some non numeric data in your list, the fileSize won't be 0 but will be the filesize of the previous iteration.

The correction would be :

```
public static long GetListSize2(SPList list)
{
    long byteSize = 0;
    long fileSize = 0;
    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
    {
        if (item.ParentList.EnableVersioning == true && item.Versions.Count > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < item.Versions.Count; i++)
            {
                if (long.TryParse(item.Versions[i]["File_x0020_Size"].ToString(), out fileSize) == false)
                    fileSize=0;
                byteSize += fileSize;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (long.TryParse(item["File_x0020_Size"].ToString(), out fileSize) == false)
                    fileSize=0;
            long.TryParse(item["File_x0020_Size"].ToString(), out fileSize);
            byteSize += fileSize;
        }
    }
    return byteSize;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this?
`
    PS C:\Users\XXXX\Documents> [Int64]$i = 0
    
    [Void][Int64]::TryParse("12", [ref]$i)
    $i
    [Void][Int64]::TryParse("2", [ref]$i)
    $i
    [Void][Int64]::TryParse("c", [ref]$i)
    $i
    12
    2
    0
`

Ughh... I can't get it to format like a post... but the example I did in PowerShell returns a 0 when parsing an alpha...

Comment: It is not possible that the previous value makes it through after the call to TryParse. A method which uses an out parameter is [required to assign a value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) to it before it returns. The documentation of [Int64.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also clearly states that the value will be 0 when the method fails.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. TryParse reassign 0 if parsing fail.